# Nodemon increasing RAM usage

Tags: memory, node.js

When I run node with the command `node ./bin/www`, task manager looks like this after 10 seconds (note that I made a setInterval returning process.memoryUsage() every 5 seconds):
[Task Manager Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxbUU.png)

But, when I run node using nodemon with the command `nodemon ./bin/www`, task manager looks like this:
[Task Manager Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkN7t.png)

- **Question:** why nodemon is using that much memory and cpu?

Comment: I don't understand the -1 on my question. I don't know if I did something wrong or there is missing information. If that's the case, I'm not doing it on purpose

Answer (score 0):

After some trying and error, I've found the reason why:

Nodemon was taken that much RAM because it was watching for changes in the main directory, which contained a big image folder (almost 7GB). I think Nodemon has to load the files content that are being watched into RAM to know when a file has changed. That's my guess.

Anyway, I've created a nodemon.json file to ignore the images folder which contains the following:

**nodemon.json**

```
{
 "ignore": ["/public/images/*"]
}
```

I placed **nodemon.json** in the app's root directory and now everything works as expected.